# moment.js difference between .weekday() and .format('d')

Tags: momentjs

Can somebody explain to me the difference of .weekday() and .format('d') in moment.js?

e.g.

```
console.log('month: ' + month.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));

let firstDay = moment(month).startOf('M');
console.log('/1 firstDay: ' + firstDay.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
console.log('/1 firstDay.weekday(): ' + firstDay.weekday());
console.log('/1 firstDay.format("d"): ' + firstDay.format('d'));

firstDay = moment('01/08/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
console.log('/2 firstDay: ' + firstDay.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
console.log('/2 firstDay.weekday(): ' + firstDay.weekday());
console.log('/2 firstDay.format("d"): ' + firstDay.format('d'));
```

produces:

```
month: 09/08/2018
/1 firstDay: 01/08/2018
/1 firstDay.weekday(): 2
/1 firstDay.format("d"): 3
/2 firstDay: 01/08/2018
/2 firstDay.weekday(): 3
/2 firstDay.format("d"): 3
```

Comment: Can you include `month` initialization? It's easier to give you help, if you convert your code sample to a runnable snippet.

Comment: Here is docs:- [moment().format("d")](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) and [moment().weekday()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/weekday/).